# Stripe payment APIs -- without using Stripe UI

Tags: stripe-payments

Can Stripe APIs be used without their client side UI ?  For example, we already have credit card info and we  want to pass it to Stripe to process charges ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use the Stripe API without [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js). I wouldn't personally recommend it since the handling your customers raw credit card information like you're describing has a host of regulatory implications which Stripe covers in-depth here:

https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide

That being said, if your business is prepared to assume that level of liability for your customer's credit card information, you can pass raw credit card information directly to the PaymentMethods API server-side as shown in the example on this page:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Once you've created the payment method, you can use the payment method like any other throughout the rest of the API.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the extra context !